# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n must be positive Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a Asteroid dodger game in Android Studio. I create random positions for each of the asteroids using the in build `random` generator in java. I keep getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n must be positive`, however it still runs fine on my phone.

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n must be positive
    at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:300)
    at ca.alnitakstudios.Asteroids.Asteroids.<init>(Asteroids.java:38)
    at ca.alnitakstudios.Screens.GameScreen.<init>(GameScreen.java:36)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:778)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:500)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:381)
```

Code:

```
public class Asteroids {

private Random random;

private int amountOfAsteroids, fastestSpeed, slowestSpeed,
biggest, smallest;
private int[] x, y, speeds, radii;

public Asteroids() {
    amountOfAsteroids = 5;
    x = new int[amountOfAsteroids];
    y = new int[amountOfAsteroids];

    speeds = new int[amountOfAsteroids];
    radii = new int[amountOfAsteroids];

    fastestSpeed = 7;
    slowestSpeed = 3;

    biggest = 20;
    smallest = 10;

    random = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < amountOfAsteroids; i++) {
        //init x & y placement
        x[i] = random.nextInt(GameScreen.width * 2) + GameScreen.width;
        y[i] = random.nextInt(GameScreen.height);

        //Setting speeds
        speeds[i] = random.nextInt(fastestSpeed - slowestSpeed) + slowestSpeed;

        //Setting the radii
        radii[i] = random.nextInt(biggest - smallest) + smallest;
    }
}

public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);

    for(int i = 0; i < amountOfAsteroids; i++) {
        x[i] -= speeds[i];
        canvas.drawCircle(x[i], y[i], radii[i], paint);
    }

    checkIfOutOfBounds();
}

public void checkIfOutOfBounds() {
    for(int i = 0; i < amountOfAsteroids; i++) {
        if(x[i] < 0) {
            //x & y placement after its been out of bounds
            x[i] = random.nextInt(GameScreen.width * 2) + GameScreen.width;
            y[i] = random.nextInt(GameScreen.height);

            //Setting new speeds
            speeds[i] = random.nextInt(fastestSpeed - slowestSpeed) + slowestSpeed;
            //Setting new radii
            radii[i] = random.nextInt(biggest - smallest) + smallest;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Since obviously `fastestSpeed - slowestSpeed` and `biggest - smallest` are positive integers, it would seem that either `GameScreen.width` or `GameScreen.height` is negative.

Comment: @matiash This is what i thought as well. But it looks like it proved us wrong. I even tried printing both out in `GameScreen` as well as `Asteroids` but still the are both positives

Comment: Just in case, remember 0 doesn't count as positive either. :) There is another chance, that `GameScreen.width` is a very large number and multiplying it by 2 causes overflow, turning it negative. But I doubt it.

Comment: The stack trace saying the problem is at `GameScreen` initialization.

Comment: @matiash I'm aware of 0 not being a positive number and i never saw 0 show up, so that counts that out. @suninsky As for the stack trace saying the problem is at `GameScreen` that's just because i create an instance of Asteroids in there.

Answer (score 2):

```
n must be positive   at java.util.Random.nextInt
```

You pass a value that is a negative to the `nextInt` method make sure that it is not negative when you deduct the `fastestSpeed - slowestSpeed` and `biggest - smallest`. Or you can also use Math.abs to make all negative numbers positive

**sample:**

```
Math.abs(fastestSpeed - slowestSpeed)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that hasn't helped. I still get the error. I guess its fine because i still runs fine on my phone, its just annoying having that error pop up.

Comment: @TouchyGibbons then make sure that the result value is not negative

Comment: I have printed every integer out and all seem to be positive. I will add some additional detail. I'm using Android Studio 0.8.0, when i get this error it also says rendering problems. I'm using a custom view on my game screen layout. Hope these detail help!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your **stack trace**, it appears the problem *maybe* because you're trying to use static members of `GameScreen` during the initialization of `GameScreen`. Are these static members properly initialized to positive values? If they were initialized to `0`, this would be a problem.

---

Since you're quite certain that it should always be positive, yet somehow you still get zero or negative values, I suggest you create a *dummy* `Random` class to debug.

```
package ca.alnitakstudios.Asteroids;

public class Random {
    private java.util.Random r = new java.util.Random();

    public int nextInt(int i) {
        //Debugging (enable if you need to trace)
        //new Exception().printStackTrace();

        //(or you can also:)
        //StackTraceElement ste = new Exception().getStackTrace()[1]; //the caller
        //print out ste.getClassName(), ste.getMethodName(), ste.getLineNumber() etc.

        System.err.println("nextInt called with value " + i);
        return r.nextInt(i);
    }
}
```

This should override the `Random` class used in your `Asteroids` class, or otherwise you may explicitly import it. No other code changes will be necessary, so you'll know for sure that you're not inadvertently fixing anything.

Comment: Thanks for the effort but its still not working. I'm starting to think this is a bug within android studio. This only started happening after i moved the class to a different package, plus it works fine on my phone so obviously it isn't an error that is produced on my phone.